# Assembly MASM: Writing to a file

Tags: assembly

I have this code

```
mov dx,offset writeme    ; address of information to write
mov bx,handle            ; file handle for file
mov cx,38                ; 38 bytes to be written
mov ah,40h               ; function 40h - write to file
int 21h                  ; call dos service
```

to write to a file. Here, `writeme` is a variable whose size is `dw` that's why it's compatible with moving to `dx`..
My problem is that I have a variable whose size is db, how do I use the code in such a way that I can move that `db` variable to `dx`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're not moving the value of `writeme` to `dx`. You're moving its address (or its offset, to be precise) into `dx`. The size of the offset will be the same regardless of the size of the data it points to.

Comment: I'm doing it this way, mov dl,offset writeme    ; address of information to write
mov bx,handle            ; file handle for file
mov cx,38                ; 38 bytes to be written
mov ah,40h               ; function 40h - write to file
int 21h                  ; call dos service but it still wont work

Comment: You should be using `dx`, not `dl`. Like I said, the size of an offset is the same regardless of the size of the data it points to.

Comment: It's impossible to say why without knowing the exact line of code that triggers the error.

Comment: I declared my writeme in the .data with a 'size' of db,, this line of code "mov dx, writeme" returns an error which says invalid instruction operands.